# sumar numeros pares de un array

Tags: javascript, array

Quiero sumar los numeros pares de un array que contiene numeros pares e impares

```
  function sumaTodosPares(array) {
  
  var numeros_pares = [];
  var suma = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] % 2 === 0){
          numeros_pares.push(array[i]);
          suma = suma + numeros_pares;   
        }
           
  }
   return suma;  
}
```

Comment: Y este código sirve?, Da algún error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás sumando a suma, el arreglo numeros_pares. Debe ser:

```
suma = suma + array[i];
```